Understanding why set theoretic intersection is not necceraly a complete intersection
If it is true that for projective varieties one can show that:
$Z(f_1, f_2) = Z(f_1)\cap Z(f_2)$
for any homogenous polynomials, than why isn't true than any set theoretic complete intersection of hypersurfaces is a complete intersection?
By arguing that
$\bigcap_iZ(f_i) = Z(f_1,...,f_d)$
Also is it true that for affine varieties any set theoretic intersection is a complete intersection by the same reasoning which may hold for affine varieties?

What is your definition of complete intersection?

Remember that the Nullstellensatz involves taking a radical

Note that the definition of complete intersection of dimension $d$ is that $I(Y)$ can be generated by $n-d$ elements.
And although it is true that when Y is a set theoretic complete intersection:
$Y = \bigcap_{i=1}^{n-d}Z(f_i) = Z(f_1,...,f_{n-d})$
We have (by Hilbert's Nullstellensatz):
$I(Y) = \sqrt{(f_1,...,f_{n-d})}$
which may have more than $n-d$ generators.

You might want to interchange d and n-d in your first sentence.
